# Can't count array returned by mysql_fetch _row

Tags: php, mysql

Like I said I can't count the results returned by mysql_fetch_row:

```
while ($a = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
 $result = count($a);
 echo $result;
}
```

It's returns (1) only why?

Comment: Read the manual. It is available online!

Comment: Are you asking why mysql_fetch_**row**() only returns one row?

Comment: I read it, and I'm searching for an hour

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: No it's the count() function it's not working, it must return a number

Comment: @Aram it will always return 1, because $a contains only one result from `while`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting a single row (most propably contaning a single field) will return 1 - as it should. Look at `mysql_num_rows()` if you want the rowcount before fetching the result, or - if you want to follow up on your own approach - do something like

```
$count=0;
while ($a = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
 //Do something with the result

 $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can always use

```
$result = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `mysql_num_rows($sql);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 3):

because you only fetch 1 row and try to count it - try mysql_num_rows

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `mysql_fetch_row` is an array of the column values for the current row. Thus, `$result` is the number of columns, not the number of rows. To get the number of rows, you could use the `mysql_num_rows` function.

BTW: Don't use that old mysql library, use mysqli or PDO.